# CakePHP - Second Level Model Association Naming Convention

Tags: cakephp, naming-conventions, model-associations

I have `Project`, `ProjectImage`, and `ProjectImageCategory`.
a `Project` hasmany `ProjectImage` and a `ProjectImage` belongs to a `Project`
a `ProjectImageCategory` hasmany `ProjectImage` and a `ProjectImage` belongs to a `ProjectImage`
How should I name the model classes respectively the database tables and foreign keys, so that CakePHP would bind them.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Project model use projects table and ProjectImageCategory use project_image_categories table and ProjectImage use project_images table, right?
the FK is ta name of the model with slug +_id , for example Project , to use a FK with this model you need set project_id , if project hasMany ProjectImage, in your project_images table you need a project_id column.